# Using query_to_xml in PostgreSQL with prepared statements

Tags: xml, postgresql, prepared-statement

I'm using PostgreSQL's function query_to_xml function to generate XML of a query result.

```
SELECT * FROM query_to_xml( 'SELECT * from some_table WHERE id = ?',true,false,'')
```

Problem is, when I use it from JDBC, with prepared Statements the '?' is ignored, so Postgres says:

```
"The column index is out of range..."
```

Is there any possible solution to pass parameters to such a query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move the `?` outside the string literal:

```
SELECT * FROM query_to_xml( 'SELECT * from some_table WHERE id = '||?,true,false,'')
```

Comment: thanks, that works out! I suppose, even if I need an ORDER BY, i can concat it by || ?

Comment: I think you'd write: `..WHERE id= '||?||' ORDER BY...',true,...`,