# PostgreSQL query_to_xml in JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

This question is very similar to [Using query_to_xml in PostgreSQL with prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897398/using-query-to-xml-in-postgresql-with-prepared-statements) however the solution there doesn't seem to be working in my case. It's actually a very odd situation. I have the following query which works fine.

```
String sql = "select query_to_xml('select col1,col2,col3 FROM table where col4 = '||?||' and col5 = '||?||'', true,true,'');";
```

and Prepared Statement like:

```
PreparedStatement ps0 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps0.setInt(1, a);
ps0.setInt(2, b);
ResultSet rs0 = ps0.executeQuery();
```

However if I add another string parameter to the query it throws an error. For example;

```
String sql = "select query_to_xml('select col1,col2,col3 FROM table where col4 = '||?||' and col5 = '||?||' and col6 = '||?||'', true,true,'');";

PreparedStatement ps0 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps0.setInt(1, a);
ps0.setInt(2, b);
ps0.setString(3, c);
ResultSet rs0 = ps0.executeQuery();
```

Throws the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "percent" does not exist
```

Where I had defined my string "c" as the word "percent". I assume this issue is actually because it is a string I'm passing into the query. I also tried hard coding the word percent into my where clause and not including it as a parameter in the prepared statement as follows;

```
String sql = "select query_to_xml('select col1,col2,col3 FROM table where col4 = '||?||' and col5 = '||?||' and col6 = 'percent'', true,true,'');";
```

but that gives the following error instead;

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "percent"
```

I'm guessing the solution is probably down to a single or double quote somewhere that needs to be added or removed, but I can't seem to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a query inside a query. So it needs to have quotes inside quotes. And for this to work, the internal quotes should be *doubled*:

```
String sql = "select query_to_xml('select col1,col2,col3 FROM table where col4 = '||?||' and col5 = '||?||' and col6 = '''||?||'''', true,true,'');";
```

The SQL literal `' and col6 = '''` is going to be interpreted on the server side as `and col6 = '`, and `''''` is going to be interpreted as `'`, thus you'll have a quote on each side of the string, which is what you need in order to tell the internal query that this is a string.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic, that worked a charm. Many thanks for the explanation too.